# Add the header x-ms-app To Kusto Spark Connector

Tags: apache-spark, azure-data-explorer

I'm tasked to identify running queries in our ADX cluster and according to MS docs we should use the x-ms-app header to identify it.

[I basically need to fill this info when checking the queries in our cluster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8STL.png)

Comment: Checking. Worst case scenario - you can log properties to ClientRequestProperties.Options

Comment: yes, I tried adding  it but didin't work

crp = sc._jvm.com.microsoft.azure.kusto.data.ClientRequestProperties()
crp.setOption("norequesttimeout",True)
crp.setOption("x-ms-app","fernando-test")
crp.toString()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this point there is no support for populating the `Application` field in `.show queries` (might change in the future).
An alternative approach would be to send client request properties.

Here is a demo (minus the credentials):

##### Spark

Install `com.microsoft.azure.kusto:kusto-spark_3.0_2.12:3.0.0` from Maven

```
kustoCluster = "https://***.westeurope.kusto.windows.net/"
kustoDatabase = "mydb"
kustoQuery = "AnotherStormEvents | take 10"
kustoAadAppId = "***"
kustoAadAppSecret = "***"
kustoAadAuthorityID = "***"

crp = sc._jvm.com.microsoft.azure.kusto.data.ClientRequestProperties()
crp.setOption("query_take_max_records", 3)        # this actually impacts the returned result set
crp.setOption("MyApplicationName"     ,"ThisIsMyApp")
crp.setOption("MyProperty"            ,"SomeValue")
crp.setOption("MyOtherProperty"       ,123.45)
 
df =   (spark.read
        .format("com.microsoft.kusto.spark.datasource")
        .option("kustoCluster", kustoCluster)
        .option("kustoDatabase", kustoDatabase)
        .option("kustoQuery", kustoQuery)
        .option("kustoAadAppId", kustoAadAppId)
        .option("kustoAadAppSecret", kustoAadAppSecret)
        .option("kustoAadAuthorityID", kustoAadAuthorityID)
        .option("clientRequestPropertiesJson", crp.toString())
        .load()
        )

df.display()
```

**ADX**

```
.show queries 
| top 1 by StartedOn
| project kv = ClientRequestProperties.Options
| mv-expand kind=array kv
| project k = kv[0], v = kv[1]
```

| k | v |
| --- | --- |
| api_version | v2 |
| request_readonly | true |
| servertimeout | 2400000000 |
| servertimeoutorigin | Gateway |
| query_datascope | 1 |
| query_fanout_nodes_percent | 100 |
| query_fanout_threads_percent | 100 |
| maxmemoryconsumptionperiterator | 5368709120 |
| max_memory_consumption_per_query_per_node | 8589699072 |
| truncationmaxsize | 67108864 |
| truncationmaxrecords | 500000 |
| **MyProperty** | **SomeValue** |
| **query_take_max_records** | **3** |
| **MyOtherProperty** | **123.45** |
| **MyApplicationName** | **ThisIsMyApp** |